# How to identify a Associations between models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have two models named `ItemDetail` and `Category`.
One controller named `items_controller`.

I want to create two tables for each model, in this each item has one category. And I want to add the category if the category is not in the list box,  which association can be use here? And I also want to know the `HTML` code for `new.html`

`ItemDetail` model:

```
class ItemDetail < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_one :category  
end
```

`Category` model:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :item_detail  
end
```

I only have `ItemDetailsController` which is generated using scaffold generator and its have all 7 actions.

My db schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20151124163435) do  
  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|  
    t.integer  "item_detail_id"  
    t.string   "category_for_item"  
    t.datetime "created_at",        null: false  
    t.datetime "updated_at",        null: false  
  end  
  create_table "item_details", force: :cascade do |t|  
    t.string   "item_code_or_name"  
    t.string   "details"  
    t.decimal  "normal_price"  
    t.decimal  "retail_price"  
    t.decimal  "wholesale_price"  
    t.datetime "created_at",        null: false  
    t.datetime "updated_at",        null: false  
  end  
end
```

Comment: Try adding a Category model... each model in Rails corresponds to at most 1 database table.

Comment: And a Item should be related to the category as belongs_to Category. (or has_many, but your requirement stated only one category)

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you will provide more details, but it looks like a good approach for this task is `STI`. It allows you create several models assigned with one DB table. Each model has own type.

Take a look [here](http://samurails.com/tutorial/single-table-inheritance-with-rails-4-part-1/) for more details.